# WordPress пагинация не перебрасывает на первую страницу

Tags: php, wordpress

Не перебрасывает на первую страницу пагинация.
Почему так может быть?

WP_Query :

```
$current = absint(
  max(
    1,
    get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : get_query_var( 'page' )
  )
);

$wp_query = new wp_query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged'          => $current,
    'orderby'      => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'      => 'lenght',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            $year_query,
            $lenght_query,
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(

        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $cateID

        ),
        
        $builder_query, 
        $guests_query, 
        $location_query, 

        $cond_query, 
        $cabins_query, 
        $type_query,
       
    ),

    ));
```

Сама пагинация

```
 <?php 
      
         echo wp_kses_post(
  paginate_links(
    [
      'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
      'current' => $current,
      'prev_text' => '<span class="icon flaticon-back">',
      'next_text' => '<span class="icon flaticon-next">',
      'base'         => '%_%',
      'format'       => '?page=%#%',
    ]
  )
);?>
```

Сама проблема заключается в том, что первая страница не перебрасывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решилась таким образом:

```
          <?php 
          
             echo wp_kses_post(
      paginate_links(
        [
          'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
          'current' => $current,
          'prev_text' => '<span class="icon flaticon-back">',
          'next_text' => '<span class="icon flaticon-next">',
        
          'format'       => '?page=%#%',
        ]
      )

);?>
```

Да, как вы видите, я убрал параметр base b и всё заработало.
Без понятия, для чего base нужен.